# AES256 OFB mode getting keystream in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, cryptography, aes

I am working on a project which involve AES256 OFB mode. Also, I am using the library from AES library from [Brian Gladman](https://github.com/BrianGladman/aes). My question is: **how can I generate keystreams?** My understanding is that i have a initial vector to start with. We would encrypt the IV to get a keystream, then the keystream is encrypted again to generate a subsequent keystream, and so on. I have the following code, but I can't seem to get the correct keystream.

```
unsigned char szKey[32] = { 0x01, 0x23, 0x45, 0x67, 0x89, 0xAB, 0xCD, 0xEF, 0x23, 0x45, 0x67, 0x89, 0xAB, 0xCD, 0xEF, 0x01, 0x45, 0x67, 0x89, 0xA8, 0xCD, 0xEF, 0x01, 0x23, 0x67, 0x89, 0xAB, 0xCD, 0xEF, 0x01, 0x23, 0x45 };
unsigned char szIV[16] = { 0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78, 0x90, 0xAB, 0xCD, 0xEF, 0x6f, 0xe2, 0x80, 0x2a, 0xa4, 0x03, 0x82, 0x8b };
unsigned char szKeystream1[16];
unsigned char szKeystream2[16];

aes_init();

aes_encrypt_ctx ctx[1];
aes_encrypt_key(szKey, 32, ctx);
aes_encrypt(szIV, szKeystream1, ctx); // generate the first keystream

aes_encrypt(szKeystream1, szKeystream2, ctx); // to generate the second keystream
```

Edit: turns out there is an typo in my key... 0xA8 should be 0xAB... sorry, and I appreciate you guys look into it

Comment: Are you developing this in C or C++? They have been evolving away from each other for three decades, and by now they are quite distinct.

Comment: doing C, but my C project can include C++ files if needed.

Comment: @LexL However the code in question seems to be only about C. The answers can be quite different in either language and if unclear, often longer unwanted discussions about the C vs. the C++ answer entail.

Comment: Also I'm not sure why you use the "sz" prefix? Is that supposed to be Hungarian notation? if so, it's wrong, because the types in question are no zero-terminated strings.

Comment: @larkey That's just to indicate the variable types. For example, sz is string, n is int, b is bool

Comment: @LexL That's called Hungarian Notation, but none of your sz-variables are **z**ero-terminated **s**trings.

Comment: I see. thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OFB works as follows:

First, you generate an IV of blocksize bytes.

Then, you encrypt this IV with the AES key.

The result of this encryption operation is used to encrypt the first plaintext block by XOR'ing it. Since XOR is a symmetric operation, the same procedure applies to decrypting the first ciphertext block to plaintext.

The result of this operation is furthermore encrypted *again* with the same AES key for encrypting the next plaintext block (or decrypting the next ciphertext block). This process is iterated until the whole data is encrypted (decrypted).

So yes, in your code here

```
aes_encrypt(szIV, szKeystream1, ctx); // generate the first keystream
aes_encrypt(szKeystream1, szKeystream2, ctx); // to generate the second keystream
```

you generate two blocks suitable for AES-ofb. What is still missing is the XOR operation with a plaintext block for encrypting (or a ciphertext block for decrypting). You can iterate the procedure for larger blocks of data.

```
char data[DATALEN];
aes_encrypt(szIV, szKeystream1, ctx); // generate the first xor block
for (int i = 0; i < DATALEN; i += AES_BLOCK_LENGTH) {
    for (int j = 0; j < AES_BLOCK_LENGTH; j++) {
        data[i+j] ^= szKeystream1[j];
    }
    aes_encrypt(szKeystream1, szKeystream2, ctx); // generate next block
    memcpy(szKeystream1, szKeystream2, sizeof(szKeystream1);
}
```

Comment: Hey Ctx, i am purposely missing the XOR part because I want to see what keystreams i generate before I XOR.Based on the documentation I am reading, the keystream I generated is invalid. The documentation i am reading is TIA/EIA-102.AAAD, specifically at page number 34 where the expected keystream is listed.

Comment: I was almost downvoting because I confused "the result of this operation" with the XOR operation. What about "the result of encrypting with the block cipher"? You can also note that if you initialize `data` to all zero bytes, that the result *will be* the key stream. XOR with a zero value is the identity function, after all.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Agreed, I added "result of this _encryption_ operation"

Comment: @LexL Unfortunately, I do not have access to that document and it does not seem to be publicly available.

Comment: @Ctx If you don't mind checking for me. The keystreams I should be getting are keystream1 A6E3 2E80 FE2E 0177 0E0F 9611 6943 CE93
keystream2 A4A4 5220 6523 E33B AD35 8AF5 71CB 029A; however, my code does not give me these results.

Comment: @LexL Impossible to say without the original document you refer to...With the key/iv you provide the first block should be c659 55f3 edb7 e020 d492 2fab 8c11 abe7

Comment: @Ctx That's the result I get as well. I have tried to reverse the bytes of the keys and IV several ways, hoping to get the correct result, but no luck so far. Thanks for verifying the result for me.

Comment: Note that there is also OFB-8, which just uses part (one byte) of the output key stream. I'll check and then go to bed :)

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I tried a aes online tool that does OFB in 8bit, and the cipher text is not the same as the documentation. Perhaps I am wrong about the byte order of the key.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes even though it's unlikely, I am starting to think the TIA-102.AAAD documentation is wrong with those keystreams. The version I am reading is from 2002, and I just found a version from 2015, so I am going to purchase it tomorrow. Will let you know if there are new info. in there. Thanks for the help

Comment: @MaartenBodewes the new document shows exactly the same thing. The keystreams it generated from the IV and key I provided is completely different than the keystreams I generate for some reason. This is a TIA standard document I purchased, so if I have questions about things like this how I can ask people for clarification? I mean most people don't have access to the document.

Comment: Well, it is possible to find it online of course. Most things are. I've *glanced at it* from within my browser, and I cannot replicate their results either. Just ask the authors for clarification, generally they should reply. My colleagues once gave me a draft international standard, and I managed to find a mistaken in there; I wasn't really supposed to review it, so that was a close call.

Comment: there was a typo in my key... 0xA8 should be 0xAB... sorry about that, and thank you